# ASP.NET publish issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish

I'm guessing I'm doing this totally wrong but I couldn't find how else to do it.

I'm trying to publish my website to a "Test server" online (hosted by One), but everything I try I end up with raw ASPX text on my screen whenever I go to the default webpage.

Using it with the ISS thingy was no problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *how* are you trying to publish? Maybe you are doing it wrong and we can correct you, but maybe you are doing it right and the problem is at the hoster?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure:

1. the hosting provider supports ASP.NET hosting
2. the .NET Framework is installed
3. ASP.NET is registered in the web server